# Docker-compose service networking failing

Tags: docker-compose

My client service keeps saying, "ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED" whenever I try to connect to my backend service. Here is my docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.4"

services:
  client:
    build:
      context: ./client-app
    ports:
      - '5001:80'
  backend:
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - '5050:5000'
```

I have it make a GET call to "http://backend:5050/api/..." but that's the error I get. Oddly enough, switching it over to "http://localhost:5050/api/..." works.

Any ideas why this is happening? For context, my frontend is a react client hosted on NGINX and my backend server is ASP.NET Core.

If I start up each container individually and have the client point to localhost, it works.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you need a reverse proxy. What does you nginx.conf look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found from another post...

AJAX request is the browser request not the server side request and your browser is not a part of mynetwork. To make ajax request (Client browser need to be public domains or map host file with service node port). You still need to map host file in your browser host machine or use full url with service node port in your gui code.

Answer (score 0):

I think your port for the backend route is wrong. Port 5050 is published to your docker host, which is why the call to http://localhost:5050/api/ works.

Instead, use the backend container's internal port and GET http://backend:5000/api/.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I tried switching the get call to ""http://backend:5000/api..." but I still get back "GET http://backend:5000/api/... net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED"